# new RSS feeds user select to update facebook app (Jobopenings) application cause an error

Tags: facebook, rss

In our Facebook application “Job Openings” Facebook user who have installed the application or want to install the app have a capability update the jobs they have interest.
Couple of days ago I have noticed the RSS feeds causes a Facebook error. Error is cause parsing the urls in the query string link 
example of RSS that get directed to facebook app is as follows.
 http://apps.facebook.com/taleojobopenings/settings.php?action=addnewrss&rssurl=https%3A//luxotticaau.taleo.net/careersection/feed/joblist.rss%3Flang%3Den%26portal%3D101430233%26searchtype%3D2%26jobfield%3D2560752046&siteurl=http%3A//luxotticaau.taleo.net/careersection/group_ext/moresearch.ftl%3Flang%3Den%26jobfield%3D2560752046&name=Custom+Job+List+%2528Human+Resources+%2526+Communications%2529

After some troubleshooting, I  noticed that when urls have **“//**” in the query string cause an error. E.g. parameter in rssurl=https%3A//……………………

I am desperate to as to how to resolve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.